# Iterating over pandas rows

Tags: python, pandas

Having a `df`:

```
cell;value
0;8
1;2
2;1
3;6
4;4
5;6
6;7
```

And i'm trying to define a function that will check the cell values of the row after the observed one. If the value of the cell after the observed one `(i+1)` is bigger than then observed `(i)`, than the values in a new column `maxValue` is equal to 0, if smaller - 1.

The final `df` should look like:

```
 cell;value;maxValue
    0;8;1
    1;2;1
    2;1;0
    3;6;1
    4;4;0
    5;6;0
    6;7;0
```

My solution that does not work yet is:

```
    def MaxFind(df, a, col='value'):
if df.iloc[a+1][col] > df.iloc[a][col]:
    return 0

df['maxValue'] = df.apply(lambda row: MaxFind(df, row.value), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html) with comparing by [`gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.gt.html), inverting mask and cast to integers:

```
df['maxValue'] = (~df['value'].shift().gt(df['value'])).astype(int)
#another solution
#df['maxValue'] = df['value'].shift().le(df['value']).astype(int)
print (df)
   cell  value  maxValue
0     0      8         1
1     1      2         0
2     2      1         0
3     3      6         1
4     4      4         0
5     5      6         1
6     6      7         1
```

Details:

```
df['shifted'] = df['value'].shift()
df['mask'] = (df['value'].shift().gt(df['value']))
df['inverted_mask'] = (~df['value'].shift().gt(df['value']))
df['maxValue'] = (~df['value'].shift().gt(df['value'])).astype(int)
print (df)
   cell  value  shifted   mask  inverted_mask  maxValue
0     0      8      NaN  False           True         1
1     1      2      8.0   True          False         0
2     2      1      2.0   True          False         0
3     3      6      1.0  False           True         1
4     4      4      6.0   True          False         0
5     5      6      4.0  False           True         1
6     6      7      6.0  False           True         1
```

EDIT:

```
df['maxValue'] = df['value'].shift(1).le(df['value'].shift(-1)).astype(int)

print (df)
   cell  value  maxValue
0     0      8         0
1     1      2         0
2     2      1         1
3     3      6         1
4     4      4         1
5     5      6         1
6     6      7         0
```

---

```
df['shift_1'] = df['value'].shift(1)
df['shift_-1'] = df['value'].shift(-1)
df['mask'] = df['value'].shift(1).le(df['value'].shift(-1))
df['maxValue'] = df['value'].shift(1).le(df['value'].shift(-1)).astype(int)

print (df)
   cell  value  shift_1  shift_-1   mask  maxValue
0     0      8      NaN       2.0  False         0
1     1      2      8.0       1.0  False         0
2     2      1      2.0       6.0   True         1
3     3      6      1.0       4.0   True         1
4     4      4      6.0       6.0   True         1
5     5      6      4.0       7.0   True         1
6     6      7      6.0       NaN  False         0
```

If shift values, get for first or last ones missing values. If necessary, is possible repalce them by first no NaN or last non NaNs with forward or back filling:

```
df['shift_1'] = df['value'].shift(2)
df['shift_-1'] = df['value'].shift(-2)
df['mask'] = df['value'].shift(2).le(df['value'].shift(-2))
df['maxValue'] = df['value'].shift(2).le(df['value'].shift(-2)).astype(int)
print (df)
   cell  value  shift_1  shift_-1   mask  maxValue
0     0      8      NaN       1.0  False         0
1     1      2      NaN       6.0  False         0
2     2      1      8.0       4.0  False         0
3     3      6      2.0       6.0   True         1
4     4      4      1.0       7.0   True         1
5     5      6      6.0       NaN  False         0
6     6      7      4.0       NaN  False         0

df['shift_1'] = df['value'].shift(2).bfill()
df['shift_-1'] = df['value'].shift(-2).ffill()
df['mask'] = df['value'].shift(2).bfill().le(df['value'].shift(-2).ffill())
df['maxValue'] = df['value'].shift(2).bfill().le(df['value'].shift(-2).ffill()).astype(int)

print (df)
   cell  value  shift_1  shift_-1   mask  maxValue
0     0      8      8.0       1.0  False         0
1     1      2      8.0       6.0  False         0
2     2      1      8.0       4.0  False         0
3     3      6      2.0       6.0   True         1
4     4      4      1.0       7.0   True         1
5     5      6      6.0       7.0   True         1
6     6      7      4.0       7.0   True         1
```

Comment: Looks sweet. But could it be re-structured in somewhat `i-1, i, i+1` form? Eventually I'd like to look at cell e.g. values of three rows before and after the observed one. E.f. at row 3 (value 6), i'd like to compare values in column `value` with rows `0,1,2` and `4,5,6`. And if the observed row has maximum value, return 1, or else 0

Comment: @energyMax - I think here is possible use `.shift(2)` or `.shift(-2)` for comparing.

Comment: Thanks. I have never used the `shift` function before.

Comment: How would you add for example `.shift(1)` and `.shift(-1)` in one line command?

Comment: @energyMax - Not sure if understand, can you explain more?

Comment: In this case you solved - it's solved for the `.shift()`. How would you solved for the case when you are comparing (in this case) two values at the same time, e.g. `.shift(1)` and `.shift(-1)`? Would you add just another columns e.g.  `shifted(+1)` and `shifted(-1)` seperately?

Comment: @energyMax - I think yes, use `df['value'].shift(1).le(df['value']).shift(-1))`, it is same like  `df['value'].shift(1) <= df['value']).shift(-1)`

Comment: Sorry. I'm lost. Could you please add this to your answer?

Comment: Looks great, but... if you look at `row` 4 - value `4`. You compare them with values `1` and `7`. So this is not max value and it should be `0`.

Comment: I finally understand `le(a,b)` function. You're comparing the `shift()` value only and not the values of the observed cell. In the case of `shift(+1)` and `shift(-1)` i'm trying to compare three values - the current row and shift values

Comment: @energyMax - exactly, you are right. So need only `df['maxValue'] = (~df['value'].shift(1).gt(df['value'])).astype(int)` and `df['maxValue'] = (~df['value'].shift(-1).gt(df['value'])).astype(int)` - shifting one column only. Similar with `.le` fucntion.